# Smooth Approximation of $L^p$ function

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation

Given a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible to approximate every $L^p(\Omega)$ function (where $1\leq p < \infty$) by smooth functions $\mathit{C}^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: This would be true, for example, when $\Omega$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to know if the result is true for general domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Given $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, you can always extend it to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by letting $f=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Omega$.

Comment: It is true for any bounded domain, no matter exterior cone condition is met or not, please check Gilbarg and Trudinger Section 7.2.